# Talend ETL automatic extraction

Tags: talend

I need a good tutorial on Talend ETL, to show how the process is done, and how we can extract files automatically, eg. (file watcher)

Thanks

Comment: Hi! I've used https://www.talendbyexample.com/ in the past, and it has lots of good tutorials. The Talend website is also good. I suggest you have a read, get stuck in and have a go. If and when you get stuck, then post a specific question, showing what you have done already, and you will most likely get help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tFileUnarchive component in talend studio to extract Zip files. The tFileList component will check for the Zip files and the tFileUnarchive will extract them. When deploying your job on TAC. You can set the time as to how frequently the job should run and check for Zip files.

[image]